# Twitter bootstrap with Knockoutjs - Radio button value

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, jquery

I have a ASP.Net MVC4 website that uses twitter bootstrap along with Knockoutjs. One of the requirements is to refresh the view model when the user toggles between some options. To do this, I have setup the following radio buttons

```
<div id = "myradio" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
  <button value="1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary active" data-bind="click: refresh">1</button>
  <button value="2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: refresh">2</button>
  <button value="3" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: refresh">3</button>
</div>​
```

My Knockoutjs view model is

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    //this function is called when the radio button is clicked
    self.refresh = function(){
    alert($('#myradio > button.active').val());
    };
}
```

The problem I am having is that the click event is firing too soon and giving me the previous value of the radio button instead of current value. To demonstrate this problem, I have setup a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/73yMR/2/

Is there any way for me to get the current value? Does knockoutjs allow the event to be passed into the "refresh" function? I am open to any idea as long as I can detect which radio option is selected when the refresh function is run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knockout passes the `event` object as the second argument (the first argument is the "current data") to the `click` handler function (you can read more about this in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html))

So the following code will produce the expected result:

```
self.refresh = function(data, element){
    alert($(element.currentTarget).val());
};
```

A working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73yMR/5/).

Comment: Thanks! I was stuck trying function(event) and couldn't get it to work. I had no idea that it was the second parameter.